# RequireJS include dependency only in build

Tags: javascript, angularjs, requirejs

I'm using [html2js](https://github.com/karlgoldstein/grunt-html2js) plugin to compile my Angular templates ( this is not really relevant but wanted to explain ).

It builds a `templates.js` during the build process that requires angular to be in scope like:

```
 angular.module("views/date.html", ...... ");
```

so essentially I need this file to be in the `main.js` dependency chain.  Now I was able to get it to be included in the build doing:

```
deps: ['templates']
```

in my `build.config` for require but its never 'required' by any modules so it never executes.

Bottom line: In require, how can I require a file at the top of the dependency chain only at build time?

Comment: As a work around I added the reference in the normal chain and use a empty file during dev mode.  Not really ideal but works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up setting a variable in the html page if in dev mode like:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">window.dev = true;</script>
```

then made a require statement like:

```
 if(!window.dev){
      require(['templates', ... ]);
 else
      // don't include templates
```